# DAX Calculated Column which sets a flag if in top N per day and per productID

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table:

```
Date    OrderNumber ProductID   Quantity
7/29/2020   1001        A           1
7/29/2020   1002        A           1
7/29/2020   1003        B           3
7/29/2020   1004        D           2
7/29/2020   1005        E           1
7/30/2020   1006        A           1
7/30/2020   1007        B           1
7/30/2020   1008        B           1
7/30/2020   1009        D           2
7/30/2020   1010        D           1
7/30/2020   1011        E           1
7/30/2020   1012        E           1
7/31/2020   1013        A           1
7/31/2020   1014        B           1
7/31/2020   1015        B           1
7/31/2020   1016        B           2
7/31/2020   1017        X           2
7/31/2020   1018        Y           1
7/31/2020   1019        Y           1
```

For each day, I need to set a flag (as a new calculated column, not a measure) for every line that has a ProductID for which the sum of all ProductID's for that day are in the top 3. For example, ProductID A would have the flag set for 7/29/2020 because the sum of the quantity for all A's is 2. But, ProductID A would not be in the top 3 for 7/30/2020. Here is the expected output:

```
Date    OrderNumber ProductID   Quantity    Top3
7/29/2020   1001        A           1       X
7/29/2020   1002        A           1       X
7/29/2020   1003        B           3       X
7/29/2020   1004        D           2       X
7/29/2020   1005        E           1       
7/30/2020   1006        A           1       
7/30/2020   1007        B           1       X
7/30/2020   1008        B           1       X
7/30/2020   1009        D           2       X
7/30/2020   1010        D           1       X
7/30/2020   1011        E           1       X
7/30/2020   1012        E           1       X
7/31/2020   1013        A           1       
7/31/2020   1014        B           1       X
7/31/2020   1015        B           1       X
7/31/2020   1016        B           2       X
7/31/2020   1017        X           2       X
7/31/2020   1018        Y           1       X
7/31/2020   1019        Y           1       X
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the Dax formula:

```
Top3 = 
var ProdId = Orders[ProductID]
var OrderDate = Orders[Date]
var SumByDate = SUMMARIZE(Orders, Orders[Date], Orders[ProductID], "Total", SUM(Orders[Quantity])) 
var topOrdersPerDate = TOPN(3, FILTER(SumByDate, OrderDate = Orders[Date]), [Total], desc)
return CONTAINS(topOrdersPerDate,Orders[ProductID], ProdId)
```

1. Capture the Product ID and OrderDate in 2 variables.
2. Create a table where we have the Quantity summarized per Date &
   ProdID
3. This table we use to get the Top 3 rows for each date by
   filtering the summary table on the orderdate. We use the column
   "Total" created on that table in previous step.
4. At last we return true when the prod id exists in the top3 table per date.

Result:[image]